# XCode 4 valid signing identity not found

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, ios5

I have installed XCode 4 for iOS 5 and when I open the organizer I see the error for my developer provisioning profile: "valid signing identity not found"

But I also have the XCode 3 in the same machine and when I open the Xcode 3 organizer, I do not see any warning.

Do I need to do anything extra to make provisioning profile valid in XCode 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but it turns out that the problem wasn't the signing identity. The provisioning profile I was trying to use didn't actually cover the new device. Once I updated the provisioning profile and then downloaded and installed the updated profile all the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, too. It works pretty fine on my own Mac Mini, while I got the error on the other Mac Mini. I exported the profiles and imported them in the other Mac, and then updated it in organizer, and it worked!